# Needed list of special characters classification with respective characters

Tags: php, javascript, unit-testing, testing

I am working on one web application , It's related to machine translation support
i.e. which takes source text for translation and translated in to user specified language

Currently it's in unit testing phase.

Here, i want to check that, whether my machine translation feature is fully working for all the special characters.
Because of different test cases I stuck at one point where i need all the special characters with classification.

**I needed all the special characters listing with classification.**

**e.g.**

**1st :**

> class name : Punctuation
>
> Characters : !?,"| etc
>
> test cases : segment1? segment2!
>   segment3.

**2nd :**

> Class name : HTML entities
>
> characters : all the characters which
>   belong under this class
>
> test cases : respective test cases

**3rd :**

> Class name : Extended ASCII
>
> characters :all the characters which
>   belong under this class
>
> test cases : respective test cases

Please folks provide this, if anyone has any idea or links so that i can make product perfect

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but in general, in the Unicode world characters are classified by "properties" assigned to them. See this [php manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) for the basic list of properties.